# Pass generic type to a generic method in scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have written a function

```
def getOptional[A](key: String) : Option[A] = {
   redisClients.withClient(redisClient =>
      redisClient.get[A](key)
   )
}
```

and I am calling it

```
redis.getOptional[List[Long]](REDIS_PREFIX_PRODUCT_IDS)
```

but this throws an exception

```
could not find implicit value for parameter parse: com.redis.serialization.Parse[A][error] redisClient.get[A](key)
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` requires an additional implicit parameter `Parse[A]`. If there is no `Parse[A]`, then it's unclear what to parse, because the type `A` is erased at runtime. Try this instead:

```
import com.redis.serialization.Parse
def getOptional[A: Parse](key: String) : Option[A] = {
  redisClients.withClient(redisClient =>
    redisClient.get[A](key)
  )
}
```